# com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads causing "your app uses interfaces that are not part of the sdk"

Tags: android, admob, google-ads-api, firebase-test-lab

I have seen that when I use Firebase Test Lab with my app apk, the following warning appears:

```
Your app uses 6 interfaces that are not part of the SDK and are not supported by Android P and later.
Landroid/os/Trace;->isTagEnabled(J)Z
Landroid /os/Trace;->asyncTraceBegin(JLjava/lang/String;I)V
Landroid /os/Trace;->traceBegin(JLjava/lang/String;)V
Landroid/os/Trace;->asyncTraceEnd(JLjava/lang/String;I)V
Landroid/media/AudioManager;->getOutputLatency(I)I
Landroid/os/Trace;->traceEnd(J)V
```

I have discovered that this warning appears when using com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads, as when I remove all the code related to ads implementation, the warning disappears. I have thought of using the following to solve the problem:

```
implementation('com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.2.0') {
    exclude group: 'android.os', module: 'Trace'
    exclude group: 'android.media', module: 'AudioManager'
}
```

But I would like to know what could be causing the warning and a better possible solition...